# How to build MyMonero wallet for Windows?

Tags: mymonero, build, light-wallet

I would like to test the [MyMonero lightweight wallet](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js) on Windows in its current state of development.

Can someone please walk me through how to package the source code to test the wallet on Windows? I understand that this is a pre-release and I don't plan to put any money in the wallet.

[I found this](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js/blob/master/docs/PRODUCTION_BUILDS.md). Ideally, I would just like a simpler and perhaps more verbose version of this.

Answer (score 3):

The MyMonero desktop app is built with [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/). To build it you need to install [NodeJS and NPM](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

After installing Node, download the source code from GitHub, open command prompt and go to the directory containing the source code, run `npm install` to grab the dependencies and then `npm start` to launch the program.