# What Android wallet options are there for Monero?

Tags: android-wallet

What are the top Android wallets for storing monero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list was updated November 2019:

Monerujo - Strong, Dedicated Monero wallet https://www.monerujo.io/

Wookey Wallet - Chinese community Monero wallet https://wallet.wookey.io/

Edge Wallet - Multi-wallet, i.e. supports multiple cryptocurrencies https://edge.app/

Zelcore - Multi-wallet https://zelcore.io/

Coinomi - Multi-wallet (closed source, but still pretty good) https://www.coinomi.com/

Guarda wallet - Multi-wallet (closed source) https://guarda.co/

Exa Wallet - Multi-wallet https://exan.tech/

Answer (score 6):

Existing: [Monerujo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.m2049r.xmrwallet) and the source can be found on [Github](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet).

Upcoming: [official GUI](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/780), [mymonero](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6fd2l9/update_about_mymonero_mobile_wallet/diifjfd/), [Coinomi (not open-source)](https://twitter.com/CoinomiWallet/status/887479515492044800) - not necessarily in that order

Available for testing: [mymonero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4421/how-to-build-mymonero-wallet-for-windows), official GUI ([build yourself](https://github.com/MoroccanMalinois/monero-core/tree/android_dockerfile/android), [pre-built apk](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/pull/780#issue-238255273))

Suspicious: Freewallet, which is custodial (they have your keys) and not to be trusted.

Comment: coinomi is custodial? i thought all their wallets in their add have a seed password to access them...?

Comment: No it's not. They're open-source and you hold the keys. I meant the infamous "freewallet" (edited for clarity).

Comment: @JollyMort Sadly, Coinomi [is no longer Open Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6rbzwm/just_noticed_coinomi_android_wallet_is_not/).

Answer (score 1):

There is [Monerujo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.m2049r.xmrwallet) and the source can be found on [Github](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet).

Comment: would suggest Monerujo, as I have used it