# I am new to crypto currency mining, from where I can get Monero wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Please help me getting monero wallet.
I am new to crypto currency mining, from where I can get Monero wallet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download for your platform from https://getmonero.org/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

As already said, get it at https://getmonero.org/downloads/

That's the "official" project page. Be 100% you're accessing that site and not some impostor site.

There's a beta Android wallet as well: [What Android wallet options are there for Monero?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4630)

However,

[**BEWARE OF PHISHING, SCAM & FRAUD SITES**](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/wiki/avoid)

See [‘xmr-wallet.org’ FRAUD](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6464) as an example. There have been many similar scams in the past. Some were copying mymonero.com design and registering a similar domain to fool users. Usually it will be paid ads on google or fake apps on app stores. Always check with some community outlet before you download software for unfamiliar cryptocurrency.