# ‘xmr-wallet.org’ FRAUD

Tags: third-party-wallets, fraud

last sunday 11/4/2017 I bought 31 Monero coins and sent them to my wallet created through ‘xmr-wallet.org’ but the money never arrived into my wallet, their support never answers my questions about this and their telephone nr does not exist.

Can anyone help me ? I have the hash of the transaction provided to me by Changelly.

Comment: even the same adres with me:
4Hm3YrYNgczRAP7jbGCZ7vA8XwbBR8DWMU7Bm9FKZqjxQXPPcwMP1kDbK3mtBSdt2c6TmLCPiMSXa39uBiEBwkg4FWbPkvPfKaZMgVDM7C

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at the Domain registration WHOIS details for xmr-wallet.org and it doesn't look good, im afraid.

The domain was only registered on 31/10/17 and the DNS servers are hosted in Russia - NS1.FIRSTVDS.RU

Here's the info..

Registrant Contact
Name: Stefan Dorner
Organization:
Mailing Address: Pfarrgasse,, Rattenberg Rattenberg 6240 AT
Phone: +43.5337643152
Ext:
Fax:
Fax Ext:
Email:zewegohe@p33.org

Registrar
WHOIS Server: whois.registrar.eu
URL: http://www.openprovider.com
Registrar: Hosting Concepts B.V. d/b/a Openprovider
IANA ID: 1647
Abuse Contact Email:abuse@registrar.eu
Abuse Contact Phone: +31.4482297

Important Dates
Updated Date: 2017-10-31
Created Date: 2017-10-31
Registry Expiry Date: 2018-10-31

Name Servers
NS1.FIRSTVDS.RU
NS2.FIRSTVDS.RU

---

I'm guessing Stefan Dorner is a bogus name.

You may want to add this to the issue on Monero reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/ as well, to see if anyone knows anymore, plus I would contact Monero devs directly - Or hopefully they will check this soon.

Dell

Comment: Devs have nothing to do with that. Devs do the devving, wider community deals with passing right information and preventing scams. PM a mod on /r/monero and he can update https://www.reddit.com/r/monero/wiki/avoid#

Also, beware of paid Google ads. Better skip those if Googling "monero wallet".

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to say but it's likely you've been a victim of a scam [phishing site](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/wiki/avoid). Nothing anyone can do about it other than warn other users.

[Quoting](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7cfds5/xmrwalletorg_fraud/dpph4ge/) Monero contributor serhack:

> It seems xmr-wallet[.]org still create for differents accounts the same monero address (it seems an integrated address): 4Hm3YrYNgczRAP7jbGCZ7vA8XwbBR8DWMU7Bm9FKZqjxQXPPcwMP1kDbK3mtBSdt2c6TmLCPiMSXa39uBiEBwkg4FWbPkvPfKaZMgVDM7C
>   They are using the Buzz template: (They didn't buy the html theme, so they have put demo links)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_58825/css/material-icons.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_58825/css/style.css">
```

> Interesting code

```
function createNewAddress(){
if($('#createNewAddress').text() == 'Loading..'){
    return false;
}

$('#createNewAddress').text("Loading..");
$.post('/index.php', {create_new_address: "true"}, function(data){
    $("#listAddress").append('<div>'+data+'</div>');
    $('.logoaddr b').html(data);
    $('#createNewAddress').text("Create New");

});
}
```

> Anyway you should avoid any service that ask you a mail and a password in order to create a Monero wallet. Use https://mymonero.com or official clients.

Also

> I can confirm that with the identical address for (probably) everybody: >I got it as well when I registred now. That's especially lazy, and of >course that can't possibly work, so it's not a legit offer.
>   Looks like an addition for the Scams To Avoid wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing with the website wallet-monero.org. It generated the same personal address to receive MONERO: 4Hm3YrYNgczRAP7jbGCZ7vA8XwbBR8DWMU7Bm9FKZqjxQXPPcwMP1kDbK3mtBSdt2c6TmLCPiMSXa39uBiEBwkg4FWbPkvPfKaZMgVDM7C.
I made a transfer of minergate to my wallet on this site but until now my wallet is empty.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you've been scammed out of your money. The site is a fraud.